# I have an issue with merging two data frames - only 4 rows are merging?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data sets of pH anomalies that were calculated from pH values in R:

ML_Law

```
        Year       ML_Law
  1:  Jan 0153  0.025538672
  2:  Jan 0174   0.02618143
  3:  Jan 0240  0.022838793
  4:  Jan 0266  0.025237142
  5:  Jan 0274  0.022844472
 ---                       
224: Jan 2018  -0.110824433
225: Jan 2019  -0.113419853
226: Jan 2020  -0.115683932
227: Jan 2021  -0.117613373
228: Jan 2022  -0.119447033
```

and
Boron

```
       Year               Boron
 1: Jan 1872 -0.0971860000000007
 2: Jan 1877 -0.0751860000000004
 3: Jan 1882 -0.0981860000000001
 4: Jan 1887 -0.0831859999999995
 5: Jan 1892 -0.0831859999999995
 6: Jan 1897 -0.0781860000000005
 7: Jan 1902  -0.100186000000001
 8: Jan 1907           -0.107186
 9: Jan 1912 -0.0771860000000011
10: Jan 1917 -0.0561860000000003
11: Jan 1922 -0.0881860000000003
12: Jan 1927           -0.079186
13: Jan 1932           -0.124186
14: Jan 1937           -0.115186
15: Jan 1942 -0.0981860000000001
16: Jan 1947 -0.0961859999999994
17: Jan 1952 -0.0981860000000001
18: Jan 1957  -0.126186000000001
19: Jan 1962  -0.129186000000001
20: Jan 1967 -0.0861859999999997
21: Jan 1972           -0.111186
22: Jan 1977  -0.145186000000001
23: Jan 1982 -0.0921859999999999
24: Jan 1987  -0.148186000000001
25: Jan 1992           -0.137186
26: Jan 1997  -0.179186000000001
27: Jan 2002           -0.147186
28: Jan 2007           -0.140186
29: Jan 2012           -0.149186
```

I am trying to merge them into one dataset based on `Year`, so any rows that match will line up, e.g. using the year 2012 it would look like this:

```
Year       ML_Law      Boron
Jan 2012 -0.097452513  -0.149186
```

But no matter which merge function I use, the only datset I get returned is this:

```
Year      ML_Law               Boron
1: Jan 1872  0.01500006 -0.0971860000000007
2: Jan 1882  0.00802408 -0.0981860000000001
3: Jan 1887 0.005794975 -0.0831859999999995
4: Jan 1892 0.004998124 -0.0831859999999995
```

with the rest of the rows saying NA even though there are matching values

I am unsure as to why only 4 rows are merging?

I have used the following merge functions:

```
merge(ML_Law, Bdata_anom)

inner_join(ML_Law, Bdata_anom)
```

and all other variances of this code, e.g. left_join etc

```
merge.data.table(ML_Law,Bdata_anom, by.x="Year", by.y="Year")

Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by= 'Year', all = TRUE),
                                  list(ML_Law,Bdata_anom))
```

And all have returned the exact same output as above

I have converted all the columns to character

I am really at a loss so any help would be much appreciated

data:

```
ML_Law <- data.table::data.table(
  Year = c(
    "Jan 0153", "Jan 0174", "Jan 0240", "Jan 0266", "Jan 0274",
    "Jan 0295", "Jan 0317", "Jan 0357", "Jan 0384", "Jan 0406", "Jan 0436",
    "Jan 0488", "Jan 0517", "Jan 0551", "Jan 0557", "Jan 0582", "Jan 0614",
    "Jan 0637", "Jan 0669", "Jan 0701", "Jan 0730", "Jan 0762", "Jan 0793",
    "Jan 0822", "Jan 0875", "Jan 0914", "Jan 0957", "Jan 0982", "Jan 1017",
    "Jan 1019", "Jan 1040", "Jan 1049", "Jan 1070", "Jan 1099", "Jan 1115",
    "Jan 1146", "Jan 1165", "Jan 1199", "Jan 1210", "Jan 1251", "Jan 1259",
    "Jan 1278", "Jan 1307", "Jan 1330", "Jan 1348", "Jan 1390", "Jan 1410",
    "Jan 1428", "Jan 1449", "Jan 1469", "Jan 1501", "Jan 1529", "Jan 1549",
    "Jan 1559", "Jan 1573", "Jan 1588", "Jan 1590", "Jan 1603", "Jan 1609",
    "Jan 1628", "Jan 1639", "Jan 1649", "Jan 1681", "Jan 1689", "Jan 1694",
    "Jan 1722", "Jan 1723", "Jan 1733", "Jan 1741", "Jan 1749", "Jan 1751",
    "Jan 1752", "Jan 1762", "Jan 1763", "Jan 1773", "Jan 1779", "Jan 1780",
    "Jan 1794", "Jan 1795", "Jan 1796", "Jan 1799", "Jan 1813", "Jan 1824",
    "Jan 1826", "Jan 1832", "Jan 1833", "Jan 1836", "Jan 1840", "Jan 1843",
    "Jan 1844", "Jan 1845", "Jan 1847", "Jan 1850", "Jan 1851", "Jan 1853",
    "Jan 1854", "Jan 1856", "Jan 1858", "Jan 1861", "Jan 1862", "Jan 1864",
    "Jan 1866", "Jan 1867", "Jan 1868", "Jan 1869", "Jan 1870", "Jan 1872",
    "Jan 1873", "Jan 1876", "Jan 1879", "Jan 1882", "Jan 1883", "Jan 1884",
    "Jan 1885", "Jan 1887", "Jan 1889", "Jan 1892", "Jan 1893", "Jan 1898",
    "Jan 1900", "Jan 1901 ", "Jan 1903 ", "Jan 1905 ", "Jan 1908 ",
    "Jan 1909 ", "Jan 1910 ", "Jan 1911 ", "Jan 1912 ", "Jan 1914 ",
    "Jan 1915 ", "Jan 1917 ", "Jan 1918 ", "Jan 1919 ", "Jan 1922 ",
    "Jan 1924 ", "Jan 1925 ", "Jan 1927 ", "Jan 1928 ", "Jan 1929 ",
    "Jan 1930 ", "Jan 1932 ", "Jan 1933 ", "Jan 1935 ", "Jan 1936 ",
    "Jan 1937 ", "Jan 1938 ", "Jan 1939 ", "Jan 1940 ", "Jan 1941 ",
    "Jan 1942 ", "Jan 1943 ", "Jan 1944 ", "Jan 1945 ", "Jan 1946 ",
    "Jan 1947 ", "Jan 1948 ", "Jan 1949 ", "Jan 1950 ", "Jan 1952 ",
    "Jan 1953 ", "Jan 1954 ", "Jan 1956 ", "Jan 1957 ", "Jan 1958 ",
    "Jan 1959 ", "Jan 1960 ", "Jan 1961 ", "Jan 1962 ", "Jan 1963 ",
    "Jan 1964 ", "Jan 1965 ", "Jan 1966 ", "Jan 1967 ", "Jan 1968 ",
    "Jan 1969 ", "Jan 1970 ", "Jan 1971 ", "Jan 1972 ", "Jan 1973 ",
    "Jan 1974 ", "Jan 1975 ", "Jan 1976 ", "Jan 1977 ", "Jan 1978 ",
    "Jan 1979 ", "Jan 1980 ", "Jan 1981 ", "Jan 1982 ", "Jan 1983 ",
    "Jan 1984 ", "Jan 1985 ", "Jan 1986 ", "Jan 1987 ", "Jan 1988 ",
    "Jan 1989 ", "Jan 1990 ", "Jan 1991 ", "Jan 1992 ", "Jan 1993 ",
    "Jan 1994 ", "Jan 1995 ", "Jan 1996 ", "Jan 1997 ", "Jan 1998 ",
    "Jan 1999 ", "Jan 2000 ", "Jan 2001 ", "Jan 2002 ", "Jan 2003 ",
    "Jan 2004 ", "Jan 2005 ", "Jan 2006 ", "Jan 2007 ", "Jan 2008 ",
    "Jan 2009 ", "Jan 2010 ", "Jan 2011 ", "Jan 2012 ", "Jan 2013 ",
    "Jan 2014 ", "Jan 2015 ", "Jan 2016 ", "Jan 2017 ", "Jan 2018 ",
    "Jan 2019 ", "Jan 2020 ", "Jan 2021 ", "Jan 2022 "
  ),
  ML_Law = c(
    "0.025538672", "0.02618143", "0.022838793", "0.025237142",
    "0.022844472", "0.022024104", "0.021059359", "0.025883042", "0.02656673",
    "0.024230239", "0.023146864", "0.02674297", "0.027137815", "0.027425885",
    "0.025055023", "0.027880042", "0.025790467", "0.023656612", "0.025062393",
    "0.026751396", "0.023158801", "0.024021308", "0.023487414", "0.024853599",
    "0.023864244", "0.02301626", "0.026366846", "0.024707991", "0.023395813",
    "0.023066953", "0.022015212", "0.021952843", "0.019644223", "0.01933781",
    "0.019647637", "0.017606901", "0.018271671", "0.017570973", "0.018611055",
    "0.020173324", "0.020435895", "0.025091874", "0.021199309", "0.018147486",
    "0.025177808", "0.022020874", "0.023522262", "0.02348618", "0.020402369",
    "0.022760424", "0.019300668", "0.018293765", "0.018805034", "0.02089096",
    "0.019980991", "0.021777552", "0.023943034", "0.029296458", "0.034300124",
    "0.030915187", "0.027265663", "0.025609317", "0.027300091", "0.027719117",
    "0.026428101", "0.025292217", "0.026858298", "0.025241441", "0.027113475",
    "0.026126364", "0.02755309", "0.025625782", "0.026680571", "0.027629678",
    "0.025807605", "0.0228546", "0.031808142", "0.02115167", "0.020306415",
    "0.022646845", "0.019699227", "0.017703624", "0.02146776", "0.015905128",
    "0.016905539", "0.018449564", "0.018044496", "0.018652316", "0.021195526",
    "0.019016396", "0.018694702", "0.014777021", "0.015324754", "0.01644359",
    "0.013308268", "0.016322315", "0.019254959", "0.015026741", "0.014371184",
    "0.016580431", "0.015001197", "0.016946782", "0.013383297", "0.011524754",
    "0.013390243", "0.015399254", "0.01500006", "0.009103739", "0.011774653",
    "0.013650684", "0.00802408", "0.011253104", "0.011896687", "0.01323429",
    "0.005794975", "0.009018997", "0.004998124", "0.006085947", "0.003644726",
    "0.005938308", "0.00429586", "0.003847151", "0.000718277", "-0.002593803",
    "0.001641481", "0.001363799", "0.000913466", "-0.002354516",
    "-0.00166087", "-0.003069858", "-0.005305801", "-0.006180768",
    "-0.003024375", "-0.006265274", "-0.006298712", "-0.006589372",
    "-0.010072961", "-0.007448448", "-0.007061415", "-0.007473857",
    "-0.009472531", "-0.010450388", "-0.009640543", "-0.009377391",
    "-0.014490683", "-0.012694552", "-0.013058953", "-0.012053629",
    "-0.015018136", "-0.014980646", "-0.014981854", "-0.01305106",
    "-0.014702017", "-0.014139295", "-0.014092611", "-0.011973722",
    "-0.016438069", "-0.014577384", "-0.014782765", "-0.015396766",
    "-0.017615694", "-0.018316043", "-0.018102521", "-0.018303113",
    "-0.019024218", "-0.020053033", "-0.0208689", "-0.021763204",
    "-0.02235716", "-0.022586569", "-0.0235081", "-0.024970031",
    "-0.02585805", "-0.026806284", "-0.028517609", "-0.029668934",
    "-0.030355954", "-0.031586143", "-0.033970788", "-0.034576466",
    "-0.035547155", "-0.03661124", "-0.03846917", "-0.04016372",
    "-0.041581613", "-0.043504771", "-0.044808369", "-0.046054884",
    "-0.047766208", "-0.049460304", "-0.050984671", "-0.052266632",
    "-0.054084116", "-0.056675228", "-0.058113755", "-0.05940037",
    "-0.060809279", "-0.061592271", "-0.062259967", "-0.06409879",
    "-0.066072931", "-0.067812188", "-0.068916747", "-0.071723257",
    "-0.073358411", "-0.074488211", "-0.07598131", "-0.077981922",
    "-0.080413345", "-0.082055846", "-0.084178979", "-0.086260313",
    "-0.087936314", "-0.089672716", "-0.091449522", "-0.093802202",
    "-0.095415347", "-0.097452513", "-0.099912722", "-0.101769785",
    "-0.103821995", "-0.10686641", "-0.108911711", "-0.110824433",
    "-0.113419853", "-0.115683932", "-0.117613373", "-0.119447033"
  )
)
```

```
Data_anom <- data.table::data.table(
  Year = c(
    "Jan 1872", "Jan 1877", "Jan 1882", "Jan 1887", "Jan 1892",
    "Jan 1897", "Jan 1902", "Jan 1907", "Jan 1912", "Jan 1917", "Jan 1922",
    "Jan 1927", "Jan 1932", "Jan 1937", "Jan 1942", "Jan 1947", "Jan 1952",
    "Jan 1957", "Jan 1962", "Jan 1967", "Jan 1972", "Jan 1977", "Jan 1982",
    "Jan 1987", "Jan 1992", "Jan 1997", "Jan 2002", "Jan 2007", "Jan 2012"
  ),
  Boron = c(
    "-0.0971860000000007", "-0.0751860000000004", "-0.0981860000000001",
    "-0.0831859999999995", "-0.0831859999999995", "-0.0781860000000005",
    "-0.100186000000001", "-0.107186", "-0.0771860000000011", "-0.0561860000000003",
    "-0.0881860000000003", "-0.079186", "-0.124186", "-0.115186",
    "-0.0981860000000001", "-0.0961859999999994", "-0.0981860000000001",
    "-0.126186000000001", "-0.129186000000001", "-0.0861859999999997",
    "-0.111186", "-0.145186000000001", "-0.0921859999999999", "-0.148186000000001",
    "-0.137186", "-0.179186000000001", "-0.147186", "-0.140186",
    "-0.149186"
  )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question to make these data and this issue reproducible?

Comment: @jpsmith I’m not sure how to make it more reproducible? What do I need to add?

Comment: As of now, no data you provided overlaps at all in year so we cant reproduce the problem. To make this reproducible, you could edit your question to include the output from `dput(ML_Law)` and `dput(boron)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding the `dput()`. The issue is that there is whitespace around your `m_law$Year` values.

As is, you will only see the same values in the four years:

```
intersect(m_law$Year, Bdata_anom$Year)

# [1] "Jan 1872" "Jan 1882" "Jan 1887" "Jan 1892"
```

But if you remove the whitespace, you will see that 25 values overlap:

```
intersect(trimws(m_law$Year), Bdata_anom$Year)

# [1] "Jan 1872" "Jan 1882" "Jan 1887" "Jan 1892" "Jan 1912" "Jan 1917" "Jan 1922" "Jan 1927" "Jan 1932" "Jan 1937" "Jan 1942" "Jan 1947" "Jan 1952" "Jan 1957"
# [15] "Jan 1962" "Jan 1967" "Jan 1972" "Jan 1977" "Jan 1982" "Jan 1987" "Jan 1992" "Jan 1997" "Jan 2002" "Jan 2007" "Jan 2012"
```

So if you remove the whitespace then merge (or join) you will get the data for all 25:

```
m_law$Year <- trimws(m_law$Year)

merge(m_law, Bdata_anom)

       Year       ML_Law               Boron
1  Jan 1872   0.01500006 -0.0971860000000007
2  Jan 1882   0.00802408 -0.0981860000000001
3  Jan 1887  0.005794975 -0.0831859999999995
4  Jan 1892  0.004998124 -0.0831859999999995
5  Jan 1912 -0.002354516 -0.0771860000000011
6  Jan 1917 -0.005305801 -0.0561860000000003
7  Jan 1922 -0.006265274 -0.0881860000000003
8  Jan 1927 -0.010072961           -0.079186
9  Jan 1932 -0.009472531           -0.124186
10 Jan 1937 -0.014490683           -0.115186
11 Jan 1942 -0.014980646 -0.0981860000000001
12 Jan 1947 -0.014092611 -0.0961859999999994
13 Jan 1952 -0.014782765 -0.0981860000000001
14 Jan 1957 -0.018102521  -0.126186000000001
15 Jan 1962 -0.021763204  -0.129186000000001
16 Jan 1967  -0.02585805 -0.0861859999999997
17 Jan 1972 -0.031586143           -0.111186
18 Jan 1977  -0.03846917  -0.145186000000001
19 Jan 1982 -0.046054884 -0.0921859999999999
20 Jan 1987 -0.054084116  -0.148186000000001
21 Jan 1992 -0.061592271           -0.137186
22 Jan 1997 -0.068916747  -0.179186000000001
23 Jan 2002 -0.077981922           -0.147186
24 Jan 2007 -0.087936314           -0.140186
25 Jan 2012 -0.097452513           -0.149186
```